# How to get data from another table

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name="driver_duties")
public class Duties{
    private String driverId;
    private String hubName;
    private String vehicleNumber;

// with getter and setters

}
```

another table

```
@Entity
@Table(name="driver_info")
public class Info{
    private String driverId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

// with getter and setters

}
```

I want to get firstName and lastName in table driver_duties on the basis of driverId how can I get this. I am new to JPA I have tried @OnetoOne but not able to implement.

Comment: Can you please post how you tried to map the ```@OneToOne``` relationship?

Comment: @KajHejer

```@Entity
@Table(name="driver_duties")
public class Duties{
    private String driverId;
    private String hubName;
    private String vehicleNumber;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "driver_info_driverId", referencedColumnName = "driverId")
    private Info info;

// with getter and setters

}


@Entity
@Table(name="driver_info")
public class Info{
    private String driverId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "info")
    private User user;

// with getter and setters

}```

Answer (score 0):

Add Duties as a data memeber in the class info

```
@Entity
@Table(name="driver_info")
public class Info{
    private String driverId;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private Duties duties;

// with getter and setters

}
```

Comment: i need data of class info in duties does it will ok to make member in info class

Comment: Yes add relationship   @OneToOne(mappedBy = "info", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
  fetch = FetchType.LAZY) it works fine

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need the following config, you should use an `id` attribute for every entity,

```
@Entity
@Table(name="driver_duties")
public class Duties{
    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "hubName")
    private String hubName;

    @Column(name = "vehicleNumber")
    private String vehicleNumber;


    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "duty_id")
    private Info info;


// with getter and setters

}



@Entity
@Table(name="driver_info")
public class Info{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private String id;

    @Column(name = "firstName")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastName")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "info", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Duties duties;

// with getter and setters

}
```